# Block alt+shift event or disable changing language in programming way

Tags: c++, windows, events, keyevent

I need to block <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> keys event using C++, or some way to block changing language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows? If so, add the appropriate tag.

Comment: If you do that, your users will hate you with passion. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: I have program that using VNC and i need to block changing language in clien-side.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ignore the invalid input characters (from other languages) than to force the users not to change language? The thing is, even if you don't let me change the language, I can still copy paste texts from my own language. I might also only have one language installed, and that not being English. If you disable ALT+Shift, you just make sure I never switch to English!

Comment: I need to block in client-side but not block in server-side

Comment: So, you actually want the language switch to happen, but on the server instead of the client? What is the **end goal** you're trying to accomplish? (Note that blocking Alt+Shift will only block the most common way of switching keyboard layouts - off the top of my head, I can think of three others that are built right into the OS, and three more that could be done with a bit of effort.)

Comment: I need to block in client-side but not block in server-side. It's because when user press alt+shift, language changing on both machines. And when on those machines different language i can't typing anything in server-side through VNC.  But if in client-side language don't change, all right.

Comment: Hmm...I solve this by setting one machine to switch layout through Alt+Shift, and the other through Ctrl+Shift (it's an option in the respective Control Panel); could you do that and reset the change after disconnect?

Comment: This way will be ok. Can you show some code?

Comment: Just blocking the Alt+Shift event can easily be done using a hook and keeping track of the states of both keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go about it a bit differently. I would catch current langauge settings at startup than change it for desired one.

At the even of alt+shift i would just set it back to the desired type again.

It should be fairy easy to do with net framework.

Here is a short article about manipulating languages: [How to change input language programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/snippets/archive/2008/12/31/how-to-change-input-language-programmatically.aspx)

And main class on msdna: [InputLanguage documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.aspx)

To actually prevent alt+shift from moving into windows system you would have to play with hooks.

Here is an article about [blocking keystrokes before windows process them.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante)

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea. You can catch `WM_KEYDOWN` message and call [ActivateKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289%28v=vs.85%29) to switch language.

Comment: To expand, your VNC client can look for the language change and change it back again.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++ you can install a keyboard hook procedure like the one suggested [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC) and filter (swallow/don't propagate) the key(s) you want to forbid.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of MSDN is that you can pretend to process `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` and then do nothing, so that Windows will not do anything further and the language will not actually change.  But some users say that doesn't work any more.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632630(VS.85).aspx

Maybe you can implement `ITfInputProcessorProfileActivationSink::OnActivated`, and when you get called you can change back to the previous language by calling `ITfInputProcessorProfiles::ActivateLanguageProfile`.  At the beginning of your app you would call `ITfInputProcessorProfiles::GetActiveLanguageProfile`.

Maybe you can implement `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink::OnLanguageChange`, set `*pfAccept`
to `FALSE` and return `S_OK`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms628770(v=vs.85).aspx

All of the above have a problem.  If the user intentionally changes languages on the client, for example by clicking on the client's task bar instead of pressing Alt+Shift, the above methods will prevent their change anyway.

I wonder if `RegisterHotKey` would let you register Alt+Shift for your own window even though the system already had it defined.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to implement is keyboard hook. The detailed explanation with source code in C/C++ can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC

Also other helpful examples can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9513/Disable-keyboard-and-show-images-for-the-children

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,
Bo